# Conflicto mootools y JQuery, alguna otra forma de hacerlos trabajar juntos diferente a usar JQuery.noConflict()?

Tags: jquery, mootools

Estaba tratando de incluir una ventana popup hecha usando la libreria Motools en un software que usa JQuery. La cosa es que, el otro software tiene 1 millon de lineas que incluyen JQuery y seria mejor no tener que cambiar en todos lados esas lineas, pero encontrar otra solucion o artilugio para hacer que ambos codigos Motools y JQuery trabajen juntos, ya sea cambiando el codigo Motools que es mas pequeño u otro artilugio?

Comment: ¿Podrías especificarnos las versiones de jQuery y Mootools con las que trabajas?

Comment: el sw tiene muchos archivos de jquery incluidos pero creo que es 1.7.2 y el de mootools 1.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de años de trabajar con Joomla!, este es un viejo problema, muy conocido en la comunidad, pues Joomla! utilizaba Mootools como su framework, sin embargo después apareció jQuery y el resto de historia la sabemos.

---

El problema radica en el uso de $ por parte de ambos, y en este caso, dada la cantidad de código de jQuery parecería que solo quedan estas opciones:

- Usar una ventana popup que soporte jQuery o que no necesite ninguna otra dependencia, algo como [SweetAlert 2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/), con eso evitarías tener que agregar otra librería/framework de JS.
- En la ventana popup que intentas agregar, modifica (o extiende si es posible) su código para que no utilice las funciones `$` y `$$` de Mootools, las cuales son "mejoras" de [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) y [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) respectivamente, lo cual no debería ser tan complicado de reemplazar, aunque depende de la implementación como esté hecha.

  Esto se explica en varias partes del sitio web de Mootools:

  http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.4.5/Element/Element

  http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode

  http://mootools.net/blog/2010/03/19/a-better-way-to-use-elements <- Este es tal vez el más pertinente.

  Aquí está la referencia (inicial) en el [código de Mootools](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/4d1e7dfe4e79287b81360e1caa017d65c91eb2f9/Source/Element/Element.js):

  ```
  if (window.$ == null) Window.implement('$', function(el, nc){
    return document.id(el, nc, this.document);
  });

  if (window.$$ == null) Window.implement('$$', function(selector){
    var elements = new Elements;
    if (arguments.length == 1 && typeof selector == 'string') return Slick.search(this.document, selector, elements);
    var args = Array.flatten(arguments);
    for (var i = 0, l = args.length; i < l; i++){
      var item = args[i];
      switch (typeOf(item)){
        case 'element': elements.push(item); break;
        case 'string': Slick.search(this.document, item, elements);
      }
    }
    return elements;
  });

  //</1.2compat>

  if (window.$$ == null) Window.implement('$$', function(selector){
    if (arguments.length == 1){
      if (typeof selector == 'string') return Slick.search(this.document, selector, new Elements);
      else if (Type.isEnumerable(selector)) return new Elements(selector);
    }
    return new Elements(arguments);
  });
  ```

---

**CONCLUSIÓN**

Dependiendo la cantidad de trabajo que haya que hacer para adaptar la "ventana popup" de Mootools, puede ser una mejor idea buscar algo equivalente en jQuery, o si tienes el tiempo y conocimiento, adaptarla para que no hayan esos conflictos, sea con JavaScript Vanilla, jQuery o Mootools.

Comment: excelente! Es una pregunta que en el foro en ingles nunca me respondieron